# Community Wiki links

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-norepro, community-wiki

I understand that there is a Community Wiki, but I've never found it.  Where would I find a link to take me there?  Is there a way that we can have a more obvious connection to the CW page?

Answer (score 4):

Community Wiki isn't a specific page; it's a status.  Posts that have been edited a lot,<sup>1</sup> and questions that attract a lot<sup>2</sup> of answers, are treated as community-owned and are automatically set to CW.  This change allows anybody to edit (bypassing reputation requirements).  It also ends reputation changes for the original author, as it's now treated more as the community's post than the author's post.

An author is able to designate a post as community wiki from the start to invite this kind of participation.  We've seen that a few times, often for posts that seek to compile a list.

Tag descriptions are also called "wikis", by the way, and like CW posts have no single owner.  (There are reputation requirements to edit tag wikis, but anybody can propose an edit.)

<sup>1</sup> Ten edits, or edits by five different people, kick a post into CW.  (I'm doing this from memory so while I *think* those are the right numbers, I could be wrong. But if so, it's close to that.)

<sup>2</sup> A question that attracts 30 (or is it >30?) answers becomes CW; the question and all its answers acquire this status.

Answer (score 2):

You can limit your site-wide searches to CW posts using the string `wiki:yes` (or `wiki:no` for the opposite effect) in the standard search bar.

Eg: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/search?q=wiki%3Ayes+bracha

You can find out more about Community Wiki posts in [our help center](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) or in the [MSO FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts).

Comment: Oh, oops.  I sure wish there were a "somebody else is composing an answer while you are" indicator. :-)

Comment: @MonicaCellio That's a known issue :) It's ok. I think our answers compliment each other well. +1 to you

Comment: Yours is the better answer in that it teaches how to fish instead of giving fish.  (And yeah, I know there's a feature request on MSO somewhere for that.)